# How to get flash's default and maximum strength levels in Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, flashlight

I've made a flashlight application and I want to add a functionality that allows the user to change flashlight's strength level if available

I already know how to change the strength level using a `SeekBar` but I want to get `int` (`Integer`) values of the default and the maximum strength levels so I can change the progress and max values of that `SeekBar`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum flash strength from it's camera characterstics.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL